# Armadillo - no member named i in matrix expression

Tags: c++, armadillo

According to `Armadillo` docs:

> .i()
>
> ```
> Member function of any matrix expression
>
> Provides an inverse of the matrix expression
> ...
> ```

However, when I try to compile this snippet:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

arma::sp_mat linReg(arma::sp_mat X, arma::sp_mat Y) {
    return (X.t() * X).i() * X.t() * Y;
}

int main() {
    arma::sp_mat X = arma::sprandu(1000, 10, 0.3);
    arma::sp_mat y = arma::sprandu(1000, 10, 0.3);
    std::cout << linReg(X,y).t() << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following error

> lreg.cpp: In function ‘arma::sp_mat linReg(arma::sp_mat,
> arma::sp_mat)’: lreg.cpp:6:24: error: ‘arma::enable_if2<true, const
> arma::SpGluearma::SpOp<arma::SpMat<double, arma::spop_htrans>,
> arma::SpMat, arma::spglue_times> >::result’ {aka ‘const class
> arma::SpGluearma::SpOp<arma::SpMat<double, arma::spop_htrans>,
> arma::SpMat, arma::spglue_times>’} has no member named ‘i’
> 6 |     return (X.t() * X).i() * X.t() * Y;
> |

I already tried with `mat` and it works fine. Any clue why it's not working with sparse matrix? And if so, how can we calculate the inverse of a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the inverse of a sparse matrix is often not desired as you end up with a dense matrix. Often the explicit inverse is not required.

Instead of taking the inverse here, maybe treat the problem as solving a system of linear equations.  Then reformulate using [solve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve) or [spsolve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve). Below is an untested example for demonstrating the general approach:

```
arma::mat linReg(const arma::sp_mat& X, const arma::sp_mat& Y) {
    arma::sp_mat A = X.t() * X;
    arma::mat    B = arma::mat(X.t() * Y);  // convert to dense matrix
    arma::mat    result;

    bool ok = arma::spsolve(result, A, B);
    if(ok == false) {
       // handle failure here
       }
    
    return result;
}
```